# get " [: if-then: unexpected operator ",when searching all sub-folder in a folder

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu

when I run this script in my Ubuntu:

```
   for item in *
do
    if  [ -d $item ]
    then
        echo $item
    fi
done
```

I got this output:
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPMMY.jpg)

I don't understand why I get "[: if-then: unexpected operator"

Comment: Please don't post any text as image. Read [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Escape your variables. Read about it [here](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting).

```
for item in *
do
    if  [ -d "$item" ]
    then
        echo "$item"
    fi
done
```